# Python 3. Вопрос про requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github, библиотеки

requirements.txt:

```
requests
beautifulsoup4
somelibrary
```

Обычно если хотят установить библиотеки, которые написаны в *requirements.txt*, пишут `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Моя проблема состоит в том, что в библиотеке `somelibrary` был замечен баг, который уже позже комьюнити поправили в *Pull requests*. Каким образом я должен написать в requirements.txt, чтобы библиотеку тянули с Pull requests.

*Я не очень сильно разбираюсь в Git*

Comment: `git+https://github.com/юзер/репа.git`

Comment: Или чтобы подтянуть конкретный коммит: `git+https://github.com/юзер/репа.git@название`, где `название` — хэш коммита или название ветки или название тега

Comment: @andreymal Если URL коммита, который находится в в Pull requests выглядит вот так: https://github.com/ramusus/kinopoiskpy/pull/47/commits/4c888bf4f6b330b115d11fac3e0b8bb177b597bb, то как это должно выглядить?